# transitive dependencies of scala project built with sbt within a different java maven project

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I have included a scala library built with sbt in a java maven project. The jar was built using `sbt publishM2`. I can use the scala classes within the library just fine, but the transitive dependencies of those classes are not added to the classpath by maven. For example one of those scala classes uses the joda-time, and this is specified in its build.sbt file as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.0"
```

Yet when running a test with `mvn test` from the java project I get a class-not-found exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/DateTime
```

When looking at the pom built by sbt and placed into the `~/.m2/...` subdirectory, I can find the following entry for joda-time:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My understanding is that maven should resolve these transitive dependencies and add them to the classpath of my current project. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `mvn -X dependency:tree`, maven says that there is an error in the groupId of the pom.xml generated by sbt.

The problem was with the value of `organization` in my build.sbt file, which contained a slash. This is included as the groupId in the pom.xml. Replacing the slash with dot and rerunning `sbt publishM2` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

SBT will, very logically, publish your library to your m2 cache when you `publishM2`, but not its transitive dependencies. If you want to put everything in your m2 repo, you can:

- use the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin to publish a fat jar with dependencies.
- use the pom which includes those dependencies, and run something like [`mvn dependency:go-offline`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) before `test`
- try this [ivy-maven plugin](https://github.com/evgeny-goldin/maven-plugins/tree/master/ivy-maven-plugin) (not tested) to help maven find your dependencies as downloaded by sbt.

Comment: I did not expect sbt to include the transitive dependencies in the jar when running sbt publishM2 in the scala project, but I expected maven to find and download the transitive dependencies when running mvn test in the java project that references the library. Maven usually does this: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies